# ¿Como hacer un setInterval en lenguaje C?

Tags: c, setinterval

Como se puede hacer una función que se ejecuta después de cierto tiempo en C o un método que sea equivalente al setInterval de javascript en C?.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tendrías que llamar a la función a si misma y con un sleep puedes colocar el intervalo de tiempo dentro de la misma función

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    elRepetido(0);

    return 0;
}

void elRepetido(int numeroRepeticion) 
{
    if(numeroRepeticion < 5){
        printf("Me estoy repitiendo \n");
        sleep(10);
        numeroRepeticion++;
        elRepetido(numeroRepeticion);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Aunque esto puede que le valga a OP en el sentido de que ejecuta algo en intervalos de tiempo predefinidos; no puede considerarse equivalente a setInterval, ya que setInterval no bloquea el hilo donde se ejecuta.

Comment: Creo que esto deberia progrmarse como `fork`